# Imgur delete anonymous upload (Greenshot)

Tags: imgur

Need your help... thanks to Greenshot a missclick is sufficient to post a picture online to Imgur. (I did...and now I want to delete it)
the picture has been posted using anonymous mode.

Because I didn't post it manually I do not have the delete link, but I have the deleteHash (15 alphanum-character).

I know there is formular to ask to delete the picture. But I would like to delete it myself.

In the plugin history I found a delete button which tell me the picture has been deleted from Imgur but the picture is still there.

I tried this : http://imgur.com/delete/ABCDEFghi01abcd
but its tells me "This isn't a valid image link! Go on, get out of here!"

I tried this :

```
  <form action="https://api.imgur.com/3/image/ABCDEFghi01abcd" method="DELETE
  <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
  </form>
```

but I got this :

```
{"data":{"error":"Authentication required","request":"\/3\/image\/ABCDEFghi01abcd","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":401}
```

(BTW how do we send a DELETE method ? it seems ignored and sent a GET instead...)

maybe the deleteHash code given by Greenshot is wrong ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 46):

This problem with greenshot still persists in 2022.

I just had the same problem and I wanted to contribute my sufferings here.

Here are the steps to get the delete hash and how to use it:

1. Go to **C:\Users{yourusername}\AppData\Roaming\Greenshot\Greenshot.ini** andopen the file using notepad or any text editor
2. Look for 'Imgur', and you should find "**Imgur upload history**" which lists all the images you've uploaded and their deleteHash
3. The deletehash is a 15 alpha-numerical characters that appear **following the  "=" symbol**
4. Go to **imgur.com/delete/{deletehash}** and you will see a prompt asking if you want to delete the picture permanently

Comment: Still works. Although the ini key is now `ImgurUploadHistory.<hash>` (just search for `ImgurUploadHistory`; the hash will be different for each uploaded file)

Comment: Thanks a lot dude you're the best

Comment: is there any trick to deactivate this imgur button from Green shot ?

Comment: @xAminex - you can configure the Imgur Plugin (Edit > Preferences > Plugins > Imgur Plugin > Configure)  in Greenshot to not "Use anonymous access". Uncheck "Use anonymous access".

Comment: And here's how to disable the plugin so you don't have any more accidental uploads: https://getgreenshot.org/faq/how-remove-plugins-or-destinations-from-greenshot/

Answer (score 24):

For those of you facing the same issue specifically with Greenshot, in the current version (1.2.10 as of 10th Dec 2018) there's an easier solution:

In the taskbar/system tray click on the Greenshot icon, then select Imgur > History and you can see a list of images uploaded there and a button to delete them. I verified this by comparing with the solution of Michel Jiang.

Comment: We're not supposed to thank people here really, but thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This should work if you pull the deleteHash from the history of the imgur plugin through Greenshot, then if you enter imgur.com/delete/{deleteHashHere} it should prompt you with the 'are you sure you want to delete y/n?' page.

Comment: This is much easier. Gives you a nice GUI to manage all your uploads.